# "which bitcoind" outputs nothing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, windows, installation, wsl

I installed bitcoind using Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu.
I see the bitcoind.exe file in the src directory, but when I run "which bitcoind" I get no output.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

`which` only searches for binaries in your `$PATH` variable (e.g. it needs to be placed in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` for that). If you didn't put `bitcoind` there, you'll need to invoke it using the pathname (e.g. `./src/bitcoind` in the directory that holds it).

Comment: This is expected after following the instructions in the doc\build-windows.md file? can I add the installation folder (/home/myuser/bitcoin) to PATH?

Comment: @RonyTesler: many open source software allows you to "auto" be added to PATH via /usr/local/bin/ if your run "make install".

Comment: @Mercedes I already ran 'make install DESTDIR=/mnt/c/workspace/bitcoin' before runnin 'which bitcoind'

Comment: /mnt/DRIVE_LETTER/*/* could be part of WSL's PATH by default, or not. I don't and won't know, I can't answer you.

Comment: What's the difference between adding /mnt/c/bitcoin to PATH and adding /home/myuser/bitcoin?

Comment: @Mercedes Or should I add '/mnt/c/workspace/bitcoin'? Because I used 'make install DESTDIR=/mnt/c/workspace/bitcoin'

Comment: @RonyTesler if it is installed there, you would want to add there to PATH